# parse xml file (xcode)

Tags: objective-c

I'm using Xcode to write a login code for an iPhone app and my code doesn't seem to be able to read my local xml file login.xml

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    users =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"login" ofType:@"xml" inDirectory:(@"Users/roaalturki/Desktop")];
    NSURL *xmlurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    xmlparsser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlurl];

    [xmlparsser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparsser parse];

}

-(void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentelement=[elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
        item =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        currentuser =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        currentpassword=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error message is?  - Are you failing to open the file? failing to parse it? you haven't given us much to go on here.

Comment: Are you sure you have the path "Users/roaalturki/Desktop/login.xml" available in your app bundle?

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is to avoid NSXMLParser. NSXMLParser is slow and inflexible.

Try to use from the beginning a DOM xml parser.
I can recommend GDataXML from the google iOS Toolkit. Very flexible. Very fast.
[Tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Or check other options.
[Here is a overview](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) of some parsers and their speed, etc.